# Error in comparison in php, to solve question with dates

Tags: php, date, comparison, diff

i'm trying to do a contract management app using php and mysql and i'm having some questions regarding the dates.

I need to know the time that there is between today and specific dates in the contract, or if there is less than a month it should display days left..

the problem is that the comparison to know if the end of contract is in the past or in the future, does'n seems to work!

link to check the code: [link to project](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/06d64fb4204faee7cc27292ccc975c306ba9981a)

```
$hoje = date_create();
$fim = '2022-11-11';
$fim_data = date_create($fim);
$diff   = date_diff( $hoje, $fim_data );
$meses =  (($diff->format('%y')*12)+$diff->format('%m'));
$dias = $diff->days;
var_dump($fim < $hoje);

if($fim < $hoje) {
    $result = "Contract has ended";
} elseif($meses >=1 ) {
    $result = $meses . " months";
    echo '<br>';
} else {
    $result =  $dias . " days";
};
echo '<br>';
echo $result;
```

Comment: What is the behaviour right now that you don't want/don't expect?

Comment: the $fim date is in the future and it is bigger than $hoje(today in portuguese), but the var_dump outputs true instead of false...

Comment: you need to convert both dates to timestamps if you want that kind  of comparison to work

Comment: @IdontDownVote - I agree, I would just add the number of months depends on which months, as not all are equal.

Comment: @IdontDownVote it actually _is_ working (when both are DateTime Objects) with a simple comparison (<, >), because datetime has the operator implemented!

Comment: `$fim` is just a string @Jeff

Comment: yup, saw it afterwards... But still, they don't need to be timestamps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing string with date object

Replace

```
if($fim < $hoje) {
```

With

```
if($fim_data < $hoje) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code with solution by Felippe Duarte

```
 $hoje = date_create();
$fim = '2018-11-11';
$fim_data = date_create($fim);


$diff   = date_diff( $hoje, $fim_data );



$meses =  (($diff->format('%y')*12)+$diff->format('%m'));
$dias = $diff->days;


var_dump($fim_data < $hoje);

if($fim_data < $hoje){$result = "não aplicavel";}
elseif($meses >=1 ){
$result = $meses . " meses";
echo '<br>';}
else{
$result =  $dias . " dias";};
echo '<br>';
echo $result;
```

Comment: does this answer add anything new but copying Felippes answer?

Comment: it shows the the corrected code for anyone that may need it.